# How can I bring down the featured image a little?

Tags: html, css, flask, bootstrap-4, web-deployment

How can I bring down the featured image a little so that it aligns with the title ?
This is web page [AnyGeeks](https://anygeeks-blog.now.sh/why-you-should-use-a-static-site-generator/)

This is the code that sets the image.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mb-3 pl-0 pt-0 pb-0 bg-white position-relative">
    <div class="h-100 tofront">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-md-6 pt-6 pb-6 pr-6 align-self-center">
                <p class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                    <a class="text-danger" href="./category.html">{% block category %}{% endblock %}</a>
                </p>
                <h1 class="display-4 secondfont mb-3 font-weight-bold">{% block ptitle %} {% endblock %}</h1>
                <p class="mb-3">
                    {% block desc %} {% endblock %}
                </p>
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{url_for('static',filename='img/avatar.jpeg')}}" width="70">
                    <small class="ml-2">RahulVk<span class="text-muted d-block">{% block dtt %}{% endblock %}read</span>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">
                <img src="{% block featuredImage %}{% endblock %}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using flask as backend. That is why the tags are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to add display flex in your div, and align-items center:

```
<div class="col-md-6 pr-0 d-flex align-items-center">
     <img src="{% block featuredImage %}{% endblock %}">
</div>
```

Or you can add some padding top:

```
<div class="col-md-6 pr-0 pt-4">
     <img src="{% block featuredImage %}{% endblock %}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you add `align-items-center` class in your `.row` class. Like @flpfar suggests, you can add in `col-md-6` class and it will work 100% but it's not straightway.

> `<div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center"></div>`